# Losing the first (if not more) row of data. not inserting into later tables. Do i need 2 cursors?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I am trying to pass a single row/entry of data into 3 tables. I first want to create a single entry in 'Calculation'. Then I want to open a loop to insert N number of entries in Calculation_value and Value. However, i noticed that only an entry in 'Calculation' is being created and nothing is being inserted into the value and calculation_value tables. How can I change my code so that I can still use the value i need for 'Data_date' from the cursor but not lose any values so that I can insert into value and calculation_value.

Below is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AGG IS
  Cursor c1 is
 select 
    to_char(to_date( TRUNC(CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy') Data_date
  , TRUNC(CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END)    Converted_Date
   , SUM(Value_Tx) as sum_of_values
   , ff.FORM_FIELD_ID
         from value v
         join submission_Value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
         join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
        where ff.form_field_id in (333, 555)
     group by TRUNC(CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END)
    , to_char(to_date( TRUNC(CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy') 
    , ff.form_field_id;
 l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
 v_value_id valuevalue_id%type;
v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
BEGIN
 OPEN c1;
 FETCH c1 into l_var;
 insert into calculation(calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, region_id, report_period_dt)
                  values (null, sysdate,  'AGGREGATES' || sysdate, 170 , l_var.data_date)
                  returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
LOOP
   FETCH c1 into l_var;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date)
                     values (null, '109', '269', 'Mwh', l_var.sum_of_values, 0, l_var.data_date)
                     returning value_id into v_value_id;
      insert into calculation_value (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id)
                                values (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c1;
END AGG;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to close and reopen the `cursor`.

```
...
...
 OPEN c1;
 FETCH c1 into l_var; --Fetch once
 insert into calculation(calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, region_id, report_period_dt)
                  values (null, sysdate,  'AGGREGATES' || sysdate, 170 , l_var.data_date)
                  returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
  CLOSE c1; --close it.

  OPEN c1; --Open again
 FETCH c1 into l_var; -- start fetching from first row again
...
...
```

Here's a Rextester Demo

http://rextester.com/live/VEJ3457

Comment: would i still be fetching starting from row #1 when i reopen the cursor?

Comment: @JohnWick : Yes. go to the link and run to check the demo example I've shown.